# Packaging system permissions in permission sets

Tags: managed-package, permissions, permission-sets

I'm trying to package 'Customize Application' system permission in a permission set. However, after installation I see that the permission set does not have the system permissions that were assigned.

Do system permissions not work with permission sets?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the reason you're needing to package the Customize Application permission in the first place?

Comment: "Customize Application" is a fairly powerful option. If I were an admin, I would not allow a package to be installed if this option were mandatory for my users.

Comment: @Mark, I want the system admin to be able to delegate admin responsibilities for the managed package to another user. This would be a delegated admin which can configure the app and change custom settings It wont be available for all users.

Comment: I would recommend you check out the concept of using a class to proxy access to read/write the custom settings records, alleviating the need for the user to have the Customize Application permissions to update your custom settings records. This might alleviate some/all of your issues trying to package this setting. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/28329/660

Comment: @Mark, that sounds like a neat approach. Will definitely consider. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 10):

As outlined in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm&type=0), you may only package the following permission set items:

> - Custom object permissions
> - External object permissions
> - Custom field permissions
> - Custom permissions
> - Custom tab visibility settings
> - Apex class access
> - Visualforce page access
> - External data source access

All other types, **including system permissions**, may not be packaged with permission sets.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. How do you package system permissions in that case? Does one have to include profiles in the managed package?

Comment: @Tan You can't package system/user permissions. It's listed in the documentation as to what you can/cannot include.