# Question on permission packaging - does User == System?

Tags: managed-package, permissions, profile, 2gp, system-permissions

This [Permission Sets and Profile Settings in Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm&type=5&language=en_US) document includes a line item:

> Do they include user permissions? No. No.

saying that these **User** permissions cannot be packaged as part of a permission set or profile.

Does that mean every permission in the **System** list here (the edit view of a profile) cannot be packaged:

[image: profile screen shot]

Comment: Yes, you are right, nothing from system block is able to be part of the package. Answered here https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/171603/packaging-system-permissions-in-permission-sets

Comment: Hi @MariiaIllarionova, Yes it does - thank-you.